# acessing new object from Object.keys and forEach method javascript

Tags: javascript, express, foreach, key

I'm trying to create a new object (newobj) with new keys and props from a poorly structured existing array of object (arrays?) ex.

```
[{"product":["1009", "name", "price", "image", "description"]},
 {"product":["1004", "name2", "price2", "image2", "description2"]}]
```

I'm getting result I want but newobj does not update outside of the scope of the forEach method (more than 1 result). My question is what am I not getting ? Is forEach incorrect method with this type obj?

```
    var newobj = {};

    Object.keys(oldobj).forEach(function(prop) {
      newobj["id"] = Number(oldobj[prop]["product"][0]),
      newobj["name"] = oldobj[prop]["product"][1],
      newobj["price"] = Number(oldobj[prop]["product"][3]),
      newobj["image"] = "url" + oldobj[prop]["product"][0] + ".jpg",
      newobj["description"] = oldobj[prop]["product"][2];
      // this works
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(newobj));
    });
   // this only updated with one 
    app.locals.newobj = newobj;
```

I've also tried mapping (w/ underscore) but I have the same result, I can't access outside scope.

```
_.each(mappedobj, function(prop) {
            _.each(prop["product"][0], function(vals){
                     newobj["id"] = Number(prop["product"][0]);
                     console.log(JSON.stringify(newobj));
            });
        });
```

Comment: You're overwriting the same properties of `newobj` each time through the loop. So the final result will just be the values from the last iteration.

Comment: `oldobj` is an array, why are you using `Object.keys()` instead of just `oldobj.forEach()`?

Comment: What is the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Why are you putting `[2]` into `description`? Shouldn't that be `[4]`?

Comment: @Barmar I have to change the property order in the new object (newobj). the original object has a different property order, i didn't provide dummy data with the correct order. apologies and thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the values from the old object, you need to make `newobj` an array of objects. You can use `.map()` to do this transformation.

Object and array destructuring is a convenient way to avoid all those hard-coded indexes. And by naming the parameter variables properly, you can use object literal shorthand to create the resulting objects more easily.

```js
var oldobj = [{
    "product": ["1009", "name", "price", "image", "description"]
  },
  {
    "product": ["1004", "name2", "price2", "image2", "description2"]
  }
];
var newobj = oldobj.map(({product: [id, name, price, url, description]}) =>
    ({id: Number(id), name, price: Number(price), url: `url${url}.jpg`, description})
);
console.log(newobj);
```

Comment: True but that's almost certainly dummy data OP threw in to write [MCVE].

Comment: @Barmar perfect thats it thank you !  I  appreciate the feedback and explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let newObject = _.map(oldObject, (item) => {
    return {
       id: item.product[0],
       name: item.product[1],
       price: item.product[2],
       image: item.product[3],
       description: item.product[4]
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert an array of poorly structured object to an array of well structured ones, you can use `Array.prototype.map` from VanillaJS:

```js
const data = [
  {"product": ["1009", "name", "120", "image", "description"]},
  {"product": ["1004", "name2", "250", "image2", "description2"]},
  {"product": ["1012", "name3", "85", "image3", "description3"]}
];

const products = data.map(({ product }) => {
  const [id, name, price, image, description] = product;

  return {
    id: Number(id),
    name,
    price: Number(price),
    image: `url${image}.jpg`,
    description
  };
});

console.log(products);
```